# Spring-boot not supported in 'DELETE','PUT' and |'GET' item by id|

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa

I'm testing a simple back-end using RESTful web service with the help of Spring-boot architecture. Now I've completed the back-end, but I cannot access `DELETE`, `PUT` and `GET` methods with `get item by id` (The other http methods work -`GET all` and `POST`)

**User Controller class**

```
package com.pali.palindromebackend.api;

import com.pali.palindromebackend.business.custom.UserBO;
import com.pali.palindromebackend.business.util.EntityDTOMapper;
import com.pali.palindromebackend.dto.UserDTO;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/users")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserBO bo;

    @Autowired
    private EntityDTOMapper mapper;

    public UserController() throws SQLException{

    }

    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<List<UserDTO>> getAllUsers() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("get");
        return new ResponseEntity<List<UserDTO>>(bo.getAllUsers(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/{userId}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getUserById(@PathVariable Integer userId) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("One");
        try {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(bo.getUser(userId), HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("No user found !!", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Something went wrong !!", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @PostMapping(
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> saveUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserDTO dto) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(mapper.getUser(dto));
        try {
            bo.saveUser(dto);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(dto, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Something went wrong", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @ResponseBody
    @DeleteMapping("/{userId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> deleteUser(@PathVariable Integer userId) throws Exception {
        try {
            bo.getUser(userId);
            bo.deleteUser(userId);
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Successfully deleted the user !!", HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("No user is found !!", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Something went wrong!!", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    @PutMapping(
            value = "/{userId}",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> updateUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserDTO dto, @PathVariable Integer userId)
            throws Exception {
        if (dto.getId() != userId) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Mismatch userId !!", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        try {
            bo.getUser(userId);
            bo.updateUser(dto);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(dto, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("No user is found !!", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Something went wrong !!", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

**AppInitializer class**

```
import com.pali.palindromebackend.util.LogConfig;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PalindromeBackendApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LogConfig.initLogging();
        SpringApplication.run(PalindromeBackendApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**SecurityConfig**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private JWTRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/authenticate").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/users").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

**MyUserDetailsService**

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return new User("admin","admin",new ArrayList<>());
    }
}
```

**JWTRequestFilter**

```
@Component
public class JWTRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JWTUtil jwtUtil;
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authorizationHeader = req.getHeader("Authorization");

        String userName = null;
        String jwt = null;

        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer")){
            jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            userName = jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);
        }
        if (userName != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null){
            UserDetails userDetails = this.myUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userName);
            if(jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt,userDetails)){
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(req));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(req,res);
    }
}
```

**CORS filter**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class CORSFilter extends HttpFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTION");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-type,Authorization");
        super.doFilter(request, response, chain);
    }
}
```

I sent `GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users and` POST http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users`headers with`{'name':'Charls','password':'asd123'}` (JSON type) and those worked.

But `GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/courses/3` - get Item by id , `DELETE localhost:8080/api/v1/users/3` and `PUT localhost:8080/api/v1/users/3` with `JSON head {"name": "Samwise Gamgee", "duration": "ring bearer"} -user update`.Those methods don't work :(

```
2021-05-20 12:55:01.798  WARN 15187 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'PUT' not supported
2021-05-20 12:55:32.746  WARN 15187 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'DELETE' not supported
```

Here, when I generate request even any method(PUT, DELETE, GET item by id) doesn't work. So the problem isn't an exception :(

Comment: have you spring security enabled?

Comment: @pL4Gu33 please check again I've added the relevant classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, Thanks for all who answered my question and I found the root of the problem :/

- In the *SecurityConfig* I've only allowed for requests which ends with  **/api/v1/authenticate** and **/api/v1/users** .

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/authenticate").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/users").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

- So I cannot pass a DELETE request which like **localhost:8080/api/v1/users/3** because it contains '/3' more than "/api/v1/users"; SecurityConfig blocks it.
- So this was the case occurs for my prob(not giving access to the security filter to pass such requests)
- If we want to get access to pass such requests we should mention relevant paths in securityConfig

Answer (score 1):

You need to set allowed methods for them. You can add a bean for that.

```
    @Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("*")
                    .allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS");
        }
    };
}
```

Note: This is code allowed all origins. You need to configure as your need.

Comment: yes bro I added those relevant content as CORS filter. I added them at the end of my question

Answer (score 1):

Change your controller methods as below

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{userId}", 
produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getUserById(@PathVariable("userId") Integer userId) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("One");
        try {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(bo.getUser(userId), HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("No user found !!", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Something went wrong !!", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @ResponseBody
    @DeleteMapping("/{userId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> deleteUser(@PathVariable("userId") Integer userId) throws Exception {
        try {
            bo.getUser(userId);
            bo.deleteUser(userId);
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Successfully deleted the user !!", HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("No user is found !!", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Something went wrong!!", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }


@PutMapping(
            value = "/{userId}",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> updateUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserDTO dto, @PathVariable("userId") Integer userId)
            throws Exception {
        if (dto.getId() != userId) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Mismatch userId !!", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        try {
            bo.getUser(userId);
            bo.updateUser(dto);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(dto, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("No user is found !!", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Something went wrong !!", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

If still not able to call your GET, PUT, DELETE methods then please check your business logic